# Installed Ubuntu 12.10 but can't login due to GPU lock and I can't boot with nomodeset because I get no GRUB menu. What can I do?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, grub2, live-usb, nomodeset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I'm a complete noob to Ubuntu/Linux. Obviously Ubuntu is having trouble with my NVIDIA card and thus produces graphics glitches and craziness at the login screen. I tried pressing SHIFT on bootup in order to boot with **nomodeset** but didn't get any Grub menu.
I can however boot my live USB stick with nomodeset. Can I install the proper GPU drivers (or restore the Grub menu) onto my HDD-installed Ubuntu from the live USB somehow?
And if so, how?

If you have a solution, please explain it to me like I'm five - I'm really not proficient at this stuff at all!
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to boot and change to console with alt + ctrl + f2. then install the nvidia driver manually with:

```
jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current
```

then reboot

Comment: That was easier than expected. :) ALT + CTRL + F2 brought me into the console and there I used
`sudo apt-get install linux-source`
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`
to install the graphics drivers. Now everything seems to work. For the moment at least. ;) Thanks!